# firebase authentication does not work in if condition

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Here i am trying to register a user with same flat number. But restrict the 2 user can register with same flat number.Here what i wanted to do is check whether any 2 user has register with same flat or not,If yes then no other member will get register and prompt a message and if no user or only 1 user has register then user can successfully get register with the system. my if condition alert value of len but when i put my code inside that condition not alert i got.

here is my code

```
registerUser(phoneNumber: number) {

alert('flat' + this.flatn.value);

var q = firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('flatno').equalTo(this.flatn.value);
q.once('value', (snapshots: any) => {
   // alert(JSON.stringify(snapshots.val()));

        this.len = snapshots.numChildren();
        alert('len ='+this.len);
    if(this.len < 2){
      this.alert('success');
      // i wanted to register user only if this condition gets true. but my code is not being perform as i want which is written after if condition.
    }else{
      //this.alert('success');
      this.alert('More than 2 users are not allowed to register with same flat');
          // flatno does not yet exist, go ahead and add new user
    }

    this.fire.auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email.value, this.password.value)
    .then(data => {
      let currentUserUid = this.fire.auth.currentUser.uid;
      this.uniqueDeviceID.get()
      .then((uDid: any) => this.uDid = uDid)
      .catch((error: any) => alert('err' + error));
      alert(this.uDid);
      firebase.database().ref('users/' + currentUserUid).set({
        ID: currentUserUid,
        email: this.email.value,
        password: this.password.value,
        first_name: this.fname.value,
        last_name: this.lname.value,
        contact_no: this.phone.value,
        flatno: this.flatn.value,
        wing: this.wing.value,
        parking_slot: this.vehicle.value,
        familyMember: this.familyMember.value,
        username: this.user.value,
        device_id: this.uDid
      });

      this.fdb.list("/users_device/").push({
        device_id: this.uDid,
        Uid: currentUserUid
      });
      console.log("got data ", data);
      //this.alert(data);
       this.alert("Registered!");
      data.sendEmailVerification().then(
        function () {
          this.alert("Email Sent Please check your mailbox!");
        },
        function (error) {
          alert("error!");
        }
      );
      this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
      if (this.authForm.valid) {
        let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
          content: 'Registering...',
          dismissOnPageChange: true
        });

        loader.present();
      this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("got an error ", error);
      this.alert(error.message);
    });

});


}
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not think that len exists in your scope. check that this property exists and not undefined this.len

Comment: if its not exist then how does is shows the exact value?

Comment: @MahiParmar check the type of len, it maybe not a number.

Comment: no its was type of any but i had also tried with number type but even my code is not working